# Vuex Getters Method Style How to Return Function

Tags: vuex

According to the Vuex documentation, you can pass a payload to a getter method as long as the method returns a function.
https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html

I'm unclear on how I can format a function that returns a function.

In my case, I'd like to pass a product object to a getter method and use the product.price data along with data in the state to return a calculated price.

Here's a stripped down version of the approach I have currently:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        product: {
            price: 12.99,
        },
        colors_front: 1,
        colors_back: 0,
    },
    getters: {
        printPrice: (state) => (product) => {
            return (state, product) => {
                var colors_front = state.print_product.colors_front,
                    colors_back = state.print_product.colors_back;

                print_price = parseFloat(product.price) + parseFloat(colors_front * 2.25) + parseFloat(colors_back * 2.25);

                return parseFloat(print_price).toFixed(2);
            }
        },
    }
}
```

When I try to access this getter in my component, I'm receiving the code of the function as a text string.

```
<template>
    <div>{{ printPrice(product) }}</div>
</template>

export default {
    computed: {
        ...mapState(['product']),
        ...mapGetters(['printPrice']),
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me understand getters that return functions better?  Is there a more appropriate way to do this?

I figured since I'm not actually mutating the state data, this method belonged better as a getter than a mutator, but I'm open to all suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you are returning a function that returns a function. I mean, you first return a function that expect a product and that function return another function that expect a state and a function. Try removing the line “return (state, product) => {“ and the closing bracket of course.

Comment: Boom!  That was it!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Nice! Do you mind if I add the answer so you can accept it? :D

Comment: Not at all, please do!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is that your getter is returning a function that also returns a function, so, when Vuex runs the function, it returns another one which seems to be cast to string (maybe by the template parser?).

Just make sure to return one single function with the expected output by changing this:

```
printPrice: (state) => (product) => {
        return (state, product) => {
        var colors_front = state.print_product.colors_front,
           colors_back = state.print_product.colors_back;

        print_price = parseFloat(product.price) + parseFloat(colors_front * 2.25) + parseFloat(colors_back * 2.25);

        return parseFloat(print_price).toFixed(2);
    }
},
```

to this:

```
printPrice: (state) => (product) => {
    var colors_front = state.print_product.colors_front,
       colors_back = state.print_product.colors_back;

    print_price = parseFloat(product.price) + parseFloat(colors_front * 2.25) + parseFloat(colors_back * 2.25);

    return parseFloat(print_price).toFixed(2);
},
```

That way we removed the wrapping function in the first level returning function.

Comment: What do you mean @elliottregan ? Returning a function on a function on a function (three functions) is not in the docs